# Rename TFS Branch Programaticly c# (TFS2017)

Tags: c#, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-sdk

I'm trying to rename a branch programaticly using "PendRename" method from Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.

Moves working, so, if I use this to move everything to a new location, it works, but what I need is to **rename** a branch.
It is possible to do this by commandline "tfs.exe rename  " (even this is given me errors if I have more than one workspace mapped for the same server url. the ... could not be found in your workspace, or you do not have permission to access it.)

So, could you please help to understand why rename a branch is not working?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you,

The problem was, there are different processes that are generating workspaces to the directory, and then, he can't remove it.

So, I solve this issue doing this steps:
1. reserve a workspace local location for my app´
2. see if this workspace is mapped. If yes, I remove it
3. create a workspace to the previous folder in path and create the map
4. get latest
5. rename

Thank you Andy-MSFT for your support.

Answer (score 0):

To [Rename or move files and folders in TFVC](http://Rename%20or%20move%20files%20and%20folders%20in%20TFVC), you must be one of the **Contributors** for your team project. See [Team Foundation Server default groups, permissions, and roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/security/permissions).

I tested that and renamed the branch correctly with the "`PendRename`" method.

Below code sample for your reference:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

namespace RenameBranch
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string oldPath = @"E:\andy\0418Scrum\web0418-0823";
            string newPath = @"E:\andy\0418Scrum\web0418-1020";
            string collection = @"http://server:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection";
            var tfsServer = new Uri(collection);
            var tpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsServer);
            var vcs = tpc.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

            Workspace workspace = vcs.GetWorkspace("YourWorkspaceName", vcs.AuthorizedUser);

            workspace.PendRename(oldPath, newPath);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need CheckIn it of course. Use a "workspace.GetPendingChanges()" and "workspace.CheckIn()" methods to do it.

[image]